# calculator validation when dividing by zero dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

im making a small calculator app with flutter
i want to add a validator to check when the second number entered is zero to avoid when dividing by zero

when the user clicks divide button it should check if it was so
i dont know how to put that so i need some help

this is my code

```
TextButton.icon(
                icon: Icon(Icons.safety_divider),
                label: Text('Divide'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    double result = double.parse(num1controller.text) /
                        double.parse(num2controller.text);
                    resulttext = result.toStringAsPrecision(3);
                    
                  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
onPressed: () {

    double num1 = double.parse(num1controller.text);
    double num2 = double.parse(num2controller.text);
    if (num2 == 0) {
      // do something here
      num2 = 1;
    }
    double result = num1 / num2; // I recommend you put as few code as possible on `setState`
  setState(() {
    resulttext = result.toStringAsPrecision(3);
  });
}
```